# Session handling in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to wrap my head around how sessions would work in Sprint MVC. If I intend to build a server that just processes requests and returns information, how should I persist sessions? I know there are many ways to do so like using cookies or sessions , but how should the architecture be overall?

Let's assume a user makes an httpRequest to a server issuing a login function and sending a body with username and password. Should I use the annotation @RequestParam for every request that the user makes regarding user data after the user has logged in.

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-session-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-sessionattributes-example) posted last year that goes through SessionAttributes and project structure of building a simple login function and viewing a user profile page. It also shows how to deploy the application.